# Dealing with touch events in Dart and IE11

Tags: dart, internet-explorer-11, dart-html

I have a fader that can be moved via touch gestures. I use `touchEvent.preventDefault();` to prevent the site from scrolling etc. This works well in all browsers except IE11.

In javaScript `touchEvent.returnValue = false;` is used to circumvent this problem.

Does anyone know how to do this with Dart?